# How to set a custom date to UUID in golang?

Tags: go, uuid

I tried to set a custom date to an UUID in golang, but couldn't able to set it. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    guuid "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    //id := uuid.NewUUID()
    t, _, _ := guuid.GetTime()
    sec, nsec := t.UnixTime()
    timeStamp := time.Unix(sec, nsec)
    fmt.Printf("Your unique id is: %s \n", sec)
    fmt.Printf("The id was generated at: %v \n", timeStamp)
}
```

Please help me in setting a custom date to UUID

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this via the `google/uuid` library. **And it shouldn't be.**

But if you really want to do it, you need to re-implement the `NewUUID` function. You could copy the code from the source and change the part where it uses the `GetTime`.